# python plotting data marker

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a data marker on a python plot that shows the x and y coordinates, preferably automatically if this is possible. Please keep in mind that I am new to python and do not have any experience using the marker functionality in matplotlib. I have FFT plots from .csv files that I am trying to compare to theoretical calculations, but I need a way of highlighting a specific point and dropping a marker that has the coordinate values similar to MATLAB. For reference, I am plotting an FFT of frequency intensity of a 100kHz sine wave with an amplitude of 1V, so I am trying to show that the spike at 100kHz is close to the calculated value of 3.98dBm in a 50ohm environment. Here is some of the data from my csv file around the point of interest (The third column is of no interest):

```
9.991250000000E+04  -8.399371E+01   0.000000E+00
9.992500000000E+04  -8.108232E+01   0.000000E+00
9.993750000000E+04  -7.181630E+01   0.000000E+00
9.995000000000E+04  -7.190387E+01   0.000000E+00
9.996250000000E+04  -7.961070E+01   0.000000E+00
9.997500000000E+04  -8.090104E+01   0.000000E+00
9.998750000000E+04  -1.479405E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000000000000E+05  3.740311E+00    0.000000E+00
1.000125000000E+05  -6.665535E-01   0.000000E+00
1.000250000000E+05  -7.868803E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000375000000E+05  -8.149953E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000500000000E+05  -7.948487E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000625000000E+05  -7.436191E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000750000000E+05  -8.068216E+01   0.000000E+00
1.000875000000E+05  -7.998886E+01   0.000000E+00
1.001000000000E+05  -8.316663E+01   0.000000E+00
```

Here is how I am extracting the data

```
Frequency = data[:,0]
Intensity = data[:,1]

title("Frequency Intensity")
xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
ylabel("Intensity [dBm]")
plot(Frequency, Intensity)
grid();
```

Edit:
I would like my plot to look something like this where x shows the frequency and y shows the intensity in dBm. I simply want the marker I place to show the x,y coordinates on the plot.

[image: FFT plot desired marker]

Comment: Could you mock (just draw in the image editor) the picture you are trying to get? I'm actually not sure I'm understand correctly what "make a data marker" mean. You also probably can check [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html).

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov I have made an edit above in the description of my question under the "Edit:" section.

Comment: Can you clarify for me --  Is your question about (a) how to calculate the coordinates that your x, y should be at or do you already know these coordinates and your question is simply (b) how to place a marker at those coordinates?

Comment: @AlAvery my question wat how to place a marker with text at those coordinates. The answer posted below is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# assuming we are in Jupyter
%matplotlib inline

frequency = np.array(
    [  99912.5,   99925. ,   99937.5,   99950. ,   99962.5,   99975. ,
       99987.5,  100000. ,  100012.5,  100025. ,  100037.5,  100050. ,
       100062.5,  100075. ,  100087.5,  100100. ])
intensity = np.array(
    [-83.99371  , -81.08232  , -71.8163   , -71.90387  , -79.6107   ,
     -80.90104  , -14.79405  ,   3.740311 ,  -0.6665535, -78.68803  ,
     -81.49953  , -79.48487  , -74.36191  , -80.68216  , -79.98886  ,
     -83.16663  ])

plt.title("Frequency Intensity")
plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
plt.ylabel("Intensity [dBm]")
plt.plot(frequency, intensity)
x = frequency[7]
y = intensity[7]
plt.plot([x], [y], 'v', color='red', ms=10)
plt.text(x, y, "({:0.2f}, {:0.2f})".format(x, y))
plt.grid()
```

[image: picture with marker]

Comment: @nichollsg, you're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, you can accept an answer by clicking on checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `pd.Series` from `data`

```
s = pd.DataFrame({
        'Frequency [Hz]': data[:, 0],
        'Intensity [dBm]': data[:, 1]
    }).set_index('Frequency [Hz]')['Intensity [dBm]']
```

Then plot with [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html)

```
ax = s.plot(title='Frequency Intensity')
ax.set_ylabel(s.name)
point = (s.index[7], s.values[7])
ax.annotate('Marker', xy=point, xytext=(0.1, 0.95), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )
```

[image]